# WebDriver close Internet Explorer after test

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, webdriver

I'm running **WebDriver** tests in **Ruby** and I've got a problem with closing **Internet Explorer** browser: when I suppose to close browser's window, IE pop-ups with the prompt "**Are you sure want to leave this page**" and two options are available "Leave this page" and "Stay on this page".

I've tried several methods for closing browser, both without success:

```
driver.quit
driver.close
```

Also WebDriver doesn't recognize this pop-up as JavaScript pop-up so

```
driver.alert.ok 
driver.switch_to.alert
```

methods are also not applicable.
I'm using **IE9** and **IEDriverServerx86 v. 2.24.2**

I appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to suppress the `onbeforeunload` event first:

```
driver.execute_script "window.onbeforeunload = function(e){};"
driver.quit
```